# Interpolation on Cubism graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, cubism.js

Cubism was designed, by mbostock's own words, for maximum information density - which means it generally wants to display one datapoint per pixel. While this is useful in many cases, it doesn't help when your data itself is not that dense. In these cases, you get ugly, staccato-style graphs like so:

[image]

Is there a way to interpolate my data/graph within Cubism to show a nice, smoothed graph?

EDIT:

After adding keepLastValue to the metric, I get this:

[image]

Here is the same data as shown in Graphite:
[image]

I would like to smooth the Cubism view to look more like Graphite (with the added awesomeness of the horizon overplotting)

Comment: It looks like you are missing some data. If you're using Graphite, did you try [keepLastValue](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.keepLastValue)?

Comment: that does seem to help, but is there any way to go a step further and smooth the resulting graph?

Answer (score 2):

Cubism doesn't do this automatically, but d3 has an interpolator you can use to fill in the in-between values. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/3310323) is an example from Mike Bostock using a custom line interpolator; you're probably fine with the default one.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for something like that